# Как сделать, чтобы не экземпляр , а сам класс возвращал значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Предположим есть `class Square():` Реально ли сделать так, чтобы при вызове `print(Square(5))`
выводилось `25` , т.е. типа квадрат стороны? Я попробовал через `__call__`, но у меня это работает только с экземплярами класса, а если делать через переопределение `__str__ / __repr__`, то можно вернуть только строку, а мне необходимо вернуть именно число, чтобы потом была возможность сделать из аналогичных классов список для сортировки.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если вопрос практический, а не теоретический, то тут вообще не нужен класс. Напишите просто функцию.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793600/decorate-call-with-staticmethod

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вариантов много, вот некоторые:

1. Переопределяем `__new__`

```
class Square:
    def __new__(cls, x):
        return x * x
```

2. Переопредяем `__call__` метакласса

```
class M(type):
    def __call__(self, x):
        return x * x

class Square(metaclass=M):
    pass
```

3. Наследуемся от `int`, переопредеяем конструктор

```
class Square(int):
    def __new__(cls, x):
        return int.__new__(cls, x * x)
```

4. Переопредяем метод преобразования объекта в строковое представление

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.x ** 2}'
```

Comment: А вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, подсказать, почему, в 1м примере мы переопределяем метод  ```__new__ ```, а во 2м примере метод ```__call__``` ? Получается, что, создаваемые метаклассом классы являются его экземплярами и поэтому с ними работает метод ```__call__ ```?

Comment: @TobaSko да, все верно `type(Square) is M`. Метакласс это класс для класса, так же как сам класс - класс для объекта. Метаклассом по умолчанию является `type`, именно в нем есть метод `__call__`, вызов которого констуирует объект (вызывая `__new__`, `__init__` итд)

Answer (score -1):

```
class Square():
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.value=n**2
        
print(Square(5).value)
```